# handling a sequence of pyparsing expressions in any order and number

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, pyparsing

Using pyparsing, I need to specify that two expressions can occur in any order and in any number between two braces. Below is my code.

```
import pyparsing as pp

def updateList(someList):
    def parseAction(str, loc, tokens):
        someList.append(tokens[0])
    return parseAction

msgNameList = []
ident = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_" + ".")
openBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("{"))
closeBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("}"))
fieldKw = pp.Keyword("field")
fieldExpr = fieldKw + ident + ident
msgKw = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword("msg"))
msgName = ident.setParseAction(updateList(msgNameList))
msgExpr = pp.Forward()
msgBody = (openBrace + (pp.ZeroOrMore(fieldExpr) & pp.ZeroOrMore(msgExpr)) + closeBrace)
msgExpr << msgKw + msgName + pp.Optional(msgBody)

testStr1 = "msg msgNameA {msg msgNameAB {field type2 field2} field type1 field1}"
msgExpr.parseString(testStr1)
print msgNameList

msgNameList = []
testStr2 = "msg msgNameA {field type1 field1 msg msgNameAB {field type2 field2}}"
msgExpr.parseString(testStr2)
print msgNameList
```

which produces this output:

```
['msgNameA', 'msgNameAB', 'type2', 'field2', 'type1', 'field1']
[]
```

Note that I add to msgNameList only upon parsing the msgName expression. (The eventual expression and parse functions for it will be more complicated.)

The output I want, for both test strings is:

```
['msgNameA', 'msgNameAB']
```

I am certain that my parsing expression for msgBody is incorrect, but I cannot figure out how to express what I need in pyparsing. Within the braces, msgExpr or a fieldExpr can occur in any order and in any number (msgExpr ... fieldExpr ... or fieldExpr ... msgExpr ...). Some examples:

1. msgExpr msgExpr fieldExpr fieldExpr fieldExpr msgExpr
2. fieldExpr msgExpr fieldExpr fieldExpr msgExpr fieldExpr
3. msgExpr fieldExpr fieldExpr

I know there must be a way to do this, but I`m missing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(First, in the future, please prepare a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question. The gist of your question is

> Using pyparsing, I need to specify that two expressions can occur in any order and in any number between two braces. Below is my code.

so please prepare a question containing only enough details for that.)

Suppose we start with

```
from pyparsing import *

foo = Literal('foo')
bar = Literal('bar')
```

Then to specify "any order and any number between the brackets"

```
openBrace = Suppress(Literal("{"))
closeBrace = Suppress(Literal("}"))

foo_or_bar = foo | bar
content = ZeroOrMore(foo_or_bar)
exp = openBrace + content + closeBrace
```

Now we can check:

```
In [40]: exp.parseString('{foo}')
Out[40]: (['foo'], {})

In [41]: exp.parseString('{foobarfoo}')
Out[41]: (['foo', 'bar', 'foo'], {})
```

Comment: I changed I tried msgBody = openBrace + pp.ZeroOrMore(msgExpr | fieldExpr) + closeBrace, but this still does not work. There must be something else I`m missing. I included more code because I thought this may not be the problem.

Comment: @XYZ - you'll need to be more specific about what it is about this expression that "does not work".

Comment: Never mind. I have a different problem than what I thought. Thanks

Comment: @XYZ This is what the answer showed, basically, no? That the problem was not in the zero-or-more of something or other. Pyparsing is built recursively. If you pinpoint what's not working and ask about it, I think you'll get answers that help you more than simply indicating a direction that is not the problem.